# Error creating new Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devkit

I am trying to create a new Rails app, but I am getting the following error:

```
D:\>rails new blog
D:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require':
    cannot load such file -- D:/config/boot (LoadError)
      from D:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:5
5:in `require' from script/rails:5:in `<main>'
```

If I change the directory to the C drive, I am able to create it.

Comment: rails is not installed successfully. What is your rails version?

Comment: @Emu I had installed rails 4.2.3. If I am checking the rails version from my C drive, It is showing the version. But If i changed the directory to D: and tried, it is giving the same error

Answer (score 0):

Do in `D drive` -

```
 gem install rails --include-dependencies
```

and then try -

```
rails new blog
```